# Log4j2 not able to send mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I have this controller class and log4j2 .
But I am not able to receive email in myemail@gmail.com.
What I  am doing wrong? I am using latest version of spring boot.

```
        // Logger statement in controller class
        LOGGER.info(" send email : " +  EMAIL);
        LOGGER.error(" send email : " +  EMAIL);
        LOGGER.warn(" send email : " +  EMAIL);
```

This is my log4j2.xml file under resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="warn" name="omnichannel">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_CONSOLE">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight{%5p} ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_CONSOLE}"/>
        </Console>

        <SMTP name="SMTPAppender"
              from="myemail@gmail.com"
              to="myemail@gmail.com"
              subject="hi"
              smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com"
              smtpPort="587"
              smtpProtocol="smtp"
              smtpUsername="myemail@gmail.com"
              smtpPassword="mypassword"
              bufferSize="1"
              smtpDebug="false">
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

            <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8" title="Error Logs" contentType="text/html"/>
        </SMTP>

        <Async name="AsyncSMTP" bufferSize="1">
            <AppenderRef ref="SMTPAppender"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.satish.central.docs.person.web.controller" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="AsyncSMTP" />-->
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="AsyncSMTP" />-->
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Is your antivirus disabled??? Antivirus sometimes causes issues. Try disabling it first.

Comment: disabled it .But its stil not working

Comment: You need to start the app in debug mode and debug the org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender  class

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows 3 log events with a comment that they are generated in the controller class. Your logging configuration shows that the Logger associated with the Controller is being routed to the ConsoleAppender. Your example above has nothing routed to the SmtpAppender.